# My focus is not removed from input after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  alert("ok");
     jQuery('input').focusout(function() {
        const label = $(this).parent().parent().find('label');
        if (jQuery(this).val() != '') return;
        label.animate({
          'font-size': '17px',
          'top': '10px',
        });

    })
}, false );
```

By clicking on send and if the sending is successful, does the plugin have an event wpcf7mailsent then I want to remove the focus from the input and turn the label into place but for some reason it doesn’t work
P.S. alert work

And these are just functions that work for me by clicking on input. Here label goes down and up

```
jQuery('input').focus(function() {
  const label = $(this).parent().parent().find('label');
  if (jQuery(this).val()=='') {
  label.animate({
    'top': '5px',
    'font-size': '75%',
  });
  } 
})
jQuery('input').focusout(function() {
    const label = $(this).parent().parent().find('label');
    console.log('Value ', jQuery(this).val());
     if (jQuery(this).val() != '') return;
    console.log('Passed if');
    label.animate({
      'font-size': '17px',
      'top': '10px',
    });

})
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a jsfiddle of this? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately not (

Answer (score -2):

try to return false or you can call focustout again on submit button (click)

Comment: understood nothing

Comment: Please provide more information. In your answers try to include why.

Comment: in the function focusout, before you end the function, return false, return nothing.

Comment: or you can call the function "focusout" again when you click the button submit/send

Comment: because you haven't provided enough information regarding your answer.. :/